# Java AWS STS get Authorization Header and Vault

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, hashicorp-vault, aws-sts

I am attempting to get the Authorization header needed so I can pass that off to vault to get a vault token.

The issue I am seeing is after calling getCallerIdentityRequest the Authorization header is missing.

Code:

```
AWSSecurityTokenService sts_client = AWSSecurityTokenServiceClientBuilder.standard().
        withEndpointConfiguration(
            new AwsClientBuilder.
                EndpointConfiguration(iamRequestUrl, regionName))
        .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
        .build();
    GetCallerIdentityRequest callerIdentityRequest = new GetCallerIdentityRequest();

    GetCallerIdentityResult result = sts_client.getCallerIdentity(callerIdentityRequest);

    Map<String, List<String>> requestHeaders = result.getSdkHttpMetadata().getAllHttpHeaders();
```

I have code in python which works perfectly

```
import botocore.session
from botocore.awsrequest import create_request_object
import json
import base64
import sys
import logging


def headers_to_go_style(headers):
    retval = {}
    for k, v in headers.iteritems():
        retval[k] = [v]
    return retval


def generate_vault_request(awsIamServerId):
    session = botocore.session.get_session()
    client = session.create_client('sts', region_name="us-west-2", endpoint_url="https://sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com")
    endpoint = client._endpoint
    operation_model = client._service_model.operation_model('GetCallerIdentity')
    request_dict = client._convert_to_request_dict({}, operation_model)
    request_dict['headers']['X-Vault-AWS-IAM-Server-ID'] = awsIamServerId
    request = endpoint.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
    # It's a CaseInsensitiveDict, which is not JSON-serializable
    headers = json.dumps(headers_to_go_style(dict(request.headers)))
    return {
        'iam_http_request_method': request.method,
        'iam_request_url':         base64.b64encode(request.url),
        'iam_request_body':        base64.b64encode(request.body),
        'iam_request_headers':     base64.b64encode(headers), 
    }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    awsIamServerId = sys.argv[1]
    print(json.dumps(generate_vault_request(awsIamServerId)))
```

What I really want to do is mimic what the python code is doing to get the GetCallerIdentity to return the authorization header that is absent in the java code.

The request headers returned in java are

```
{x-amzn-RequestId=[xxx], Content-Length=[xxx], Date=[date], Content-Type=[text/xml]}
```

Tried the above and didnt return an authorization header in the response headers, expecting it to be present.

Comment: Have you tried with the Java Vault bindings instead?

Comment: Are you saying with springboot?